# Foreground "didDiscover peripheral" update rate drop after around 115s

Tags: core-bluetooth

I have been successfully using `didDiscover peripheral` to read data, via Scan Response, from a remote sensor.

I depend on an update rate in excess of 7Hz this is a rate that see for the first 1 minute 54 seconds, after the call to `scanForPeripherals`, however beyond that time the up date rate drops to around 3Hz. The peripherals are still advertising at the same rate.

This behaviour is 100% repeatable.

I assume this is behaviour imposed by Apple to preserve battery life?

Anyone know how to disable it?

Answer (score 0):

So it would appear that simply stopping and then instantly restarting the scanning process, periodically within the 115s time frame, has the desired effect. The scanning rate stays at the pre 115s rate.

A crude but effective solution.